# Close JFace window on initialization

Tags: java, jface

I have a JFace application with a list of files. A child window is opened when a user clicked on a file in the list. The child window automatically loads the file content into a Text widget.

Loading of the file content may fail. I can detect such a situation and I would be happy to close the child window before it is shown on the screen.

I tried to call `close()` at the end of overriden `protected Control createContents(Composite parent)` method of the child window. But I got a null exception somewhere in the JFace library:

```
Exception occurred java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.initializeBounds(Window.java:758)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:435)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
```

Where is a correct place to initialize the window widgets with initial values? Ideally I feel it should meet the conditions:

- Widgets should be already created by the framework.
- The window should not be visible yet.
- `close()` should close the window correctly if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Window` object hasn't got a window shell yet, the `open()` method creates a new one and opens it. It's in its `create()` method when `createContents(Composite parent)` is called upon, along with some other method which configure some visual details. That's the `initializeBounds()` method, which relies on an already existing shell. If you close it, there you go, you got the exception.

Maybe you would want to overwrite the `open()` method itself:

```
public int open() {
   if (!condition)
        return super.open();    // as usual
    else
        return CANCEL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I cannot check it right now. But, seems, I have to place initialization code before `if`. So, the initialization code will not have access to the widgets, as the widgets are created on `super.open()` execution. Seems, I have to separate initialization code into two parts: 1) not dependent on the widgets, may fail; 2) dependents on the widgets, must never fail.